Assistance Needed for Creating Triangular Animation for a Holographic Pyramid Display
I'm currently working on a project in Unity where I need to create a triangular animation suitable for a holographic pyramid display. The display is intended to be three-sided, providing a 270-degree viewable area.
I have set up my scene with a character at the center, and I'm looking to synchronize three cameras to capture the front, left, and right views. Each view needs to be rendered as a trapezoid shape with specific dimensions to fit the sides of the holographic pyramid, and then these views need to be merged into one cohesive image that can be projected onto the pyramid to create a holographic effect.
I've set up a scene with a character and have already animated this character. Additionally, I've placed three cameras around the character to capture different angles - front, left, and right, leaving out the back view. However, I'm not quite sure what my next steps should be.
Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!
Best regards, Daniel
ResultIWant

FrontImgUnity

LeftImgUnity

RightImgUnity


Afaik you can't directly change the shape of the rendering. What you could try though is using a RenderTexture and apply that to a trapezoid shaped plane which is then finally rendered by a 4th main camera to the display .. could you add some graphics to better understand your set-up and desired outcome?

I'm new when it comes to Unity and don't quite understand how it would work, but I really need to know or be able to do it for my main project here I'll post a link to my goal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fggE3VI3NRg
Of course I have already added some pictures of what I currently already have

hm not sure - it is difficult to see from the youtube video but it almost seems like the rendering are just rotate rectangle views .. the magic converting it into trapezoid shape might actually happen somewhere else in their setup ... even in your desired output image the is actually no real stretching into trapezoid shape but rather cutting of on the edges happening - I think you could just use three trapezoid meshes, adjust the UV mapping to there is no streching of the image and then apply RenderTextures to them - your three cameras render into the render textures, a 4th one the whole image
